# How to get the slave name in a freestyle job groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, resources, slave

Let me outline my situation, and what I tried so far to give a better understanding. I have a jenkins master installed on kubernetes, and I have a freestyle job with concurrent builds enabled. I have 3 nodes (node1, node2, node3) where this job may run. Each node has a capacity to run 5 builds of the job at the same time.

Now the trouble is that I want to assign a workspace from the host filesystem running the pods (eg. -v /ws/ws1:/ws/ws1 in Docker style), because I need to preserve the workspace for later reuse. I need to do so to prevent copying huge files from the network every time a build starts.

So I want to assign a dedicated workspace to each pod to prevent any interference in the running builds. The idea is to use lockable resources which provides a variable (eg. LOCKED_RESOURCE) containing the acquired resource allowing me to set the workspace to /ws/$LOCKED_RESOURCE.

The challenge is provide the resources list. I cannot provide a static list, eg. ws1 ws2 ws3 ws4 ws5, because it caps the cluster capacity to 5 builds at a time even though it could run 3*5=15 builds concurrently. Then the solution might be to extend the resource list to node1-ws1 node1-ws2 .... node1-ws5 node2-ws1 node2-ws2 ... node3-ws5. This allows the cluster to operate at full capacity (15 concurrent builds), however sooner or later each node would have /ws/node1-ws1, /ws/node1-ws2, .... /ws/node3-ws5 workspaces. And it's a problem, because it would fill the disk.

So I need to provide a resource list like $NODE-ws1 $NODE-ws2 ... $NODE-ws5. This would eliminate the excessive workspaces and still allows the cluster to run at full capacity (=15 builds at the same time). $NODE is a environment variables inside the pod.

Too bad that the lockable resources plugin doesn't support variable extrapolation, so it uses $NODE-ws1 as a literal value, instead of expanding it to eg. node2-ws1. Unfortunately the plugin maintainers just can't or won't add this feature to the plugin for 2-3 years, so this path looks like a dead end.

Then I tried to use the groovy field to query the NODE env variable from the running pod. However, I found only examples iterating over all the running pods/slaves, eg.

```
Jenkins.instance.slaves.find { agent ->
   // do something
}
```

It's not good, because I need to find out the single agent/pod running this specific build of the job. So the question is: how to get the name of this specific slave only?

Thank you for reading it so far. Btw. I'm open to suggestion, so if the problem can be solved in a different way (efficiently), I'd gladly take it.

Comment: In pipeline job, `$NODE_NAME` contains the name of the slave. You may want to print all the environment vars with `sh "env"` and explore it.

Comment: Pay attention to the title: "... in a freestyle job". Anyway, when I print the env variables visible in the groovy script they are the master's env variables only.

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of your script, a "minimal reproducible example".